# local Notification - if the user does not first and not the second Any after 30 seconds "

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I work for local notification  and all I have built fully functional

And follows that when launches my notification

Message shows the 2 buttons
If the press on "viwe" button => it's the launches application
And if the press on "close" button of the second, he's working close

I want to,  "if the user does not first and not the second
Any after 30 seconds "
 =>    (after 30 seconds - After the end of a voice alert  "29.mp3")   but I did not press if the user does not first and not the second
Any after 30 seconds
That shows a specific sound (after 30 seconds), how can I do this

and what deligate method do that functionality

-(IBAction) scheduleNotification1 {

```
local1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

// create date/time information
local1.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2];
local1.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

// set notification details
local1.alertBody = @"2!";
local1.alertAction = @"View";


//local1.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
 //local1.soundName = @"alarmsound.caf";
local1.soundName = @"29.mp3";
// set the badge on the app icon
local1.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

// local1.repeatInterval =NSSecondCalendarUnit;////    NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
//local1.repeatInterval =1 ;
// Gather any custom data you need to save with the notification
NSDictionary *customInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"ABCD2" forKey:@"yourKey1"];

local1.userInfo = customInfo;

// Schedule it!
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:local1];

//[local1 release];
```

}

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you want, please make your question more clear.

Comment: And don't use automatic translation tools. The translations produced are often garbage so that your question cannot be understood.

Comment: You know the voice of Local Notification  duration of only 30 seconds what I want is exactly after 30 seconds to go out another voice and so remains every 30 seconds out specific sound until the user presses the button View  - when the user presses a button View, the sound stops and go for the application -  as if any alarm  that the user does not have only two choices: either just listen for the sound or open the application
I hope that you are now understood friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to schedule a second notification 30 seconds after the first one, and cancel it if the user presses the view button. You can't have a timer built in to the system notification alert.

Comment: This is exactly what I want - how